# JWT Token as source of User Details in an API?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, firebase-authentication, jwt

I'm building out a backend REST API app, and it takes in requests from a client that uses Firebase Authentication, which will be passing in the JWT Token in the headers of all requests.

Should I still require UserID in the request body for requests, or should I just have the JWT Token be my source for decoding and fetching the UserID for all requests?

Using SpringBoot, and I think I can create a filter to decode the JWT for all requests and then create a User object that can be referenced throughout the chain.

But I'm not sure if it still makes sense to also require the UserID, if anything just as a point of documentation to say the UserID is being used here to handle business logic. Watcha think?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this would make any sense. You wouldn't actually use the value from the request body anywhere in the code, would you? Since your concern seems to be abobut documentation I'd rather clearly describe that resources in your application are bound to the authenticated user.